# When using ActionChains, is it possible to click on an element, perform some actions, go back to the previous page and continue to the next item?

Tags: python, loops, selenium

I'm using ActionChains in a loop and I'm trying to figure out how to click on an item and perform some actions if certain conditions are met, in my case if the item isn't sold out and go back to the previous page to continue the loop. Is it possible to do so or should I be using a different method? The code I have below works fine until I click on the available item and go to a different url, which triggers a stale element error.

```
articles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
for article in articles:
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(article).perform()
if article.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text == "sold out":
    print("sold out")
else:
    print("available")
name = article.find_element_by_xpath("div/h1/a")
color = article.find_element_by_xpath("div/p/a")
name_text = name.text
color_text = color.text
print name_text, color_text
link = article.find_element_by_xpath('div/a').get_attribute('href')
print(link)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="add-remove- 
buttons"]/input""").click() 
(...)
(...)
continue
```

new set-up although I'm getting a 'list index out of range' error now.

```
articles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
for i in range(len(articles)):
    article = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')[i]
    if article.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text == "sold out":
        print("sold out")
    else:
        print("available")
    name = article.find_element_by_xpath("div/h1/a")
    color = article.find_element_by_xpath("div/p/a")
    name_text = name.text
    color_text = color.text
    print name_text, color_text
    link = article.find_element_by_xpath('div/a').get_attribute('href')
    print(link)
    driver.get(link)
    (...)
    (...)
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a StaleElementReferenceException whenever you hold a variable to an element on the page and something in the page changes or the page refreshes.

What you should do initiate a new variable *inside* the loop. In this way, every time you iterate through the loop and the page is (possibly) refreshed, there is a new variable and the exception doesn't occur.

Something like this to start your loop.

```
# look up the articles one time outside of the loop, so we can check the number of articles
articles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')

# loop through the articles, based on the number of articles (length of list)
for i in range(len(articles)):
    # each time in the for loop, look up the list of articles again and then go for element number i
    article = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')[i]
```

Comment: so should it look like this? I just updated the original post but I'm getting a 'list index out of range error' now though.

Comment: Maybe you can add some extra print statements before and in the the loop, and check how many items  driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article') returns and what the actual value if 'i' is. It could be that initially there are like 10 articles and that during the test (possibly because of your interactions) only 9 articles remain? I obviously haven't been able to run the code myself.